# Basic networking problem with Ubuntu 9.04 on Acer Extensa 5635Z laptop

Tags: ubuntu, networking, laptop

I just installed Ubuntu 9.04 on a brand new [Acer Extensa 5635Z](http://www.geekwithlaptop.com/acer-extensa-5635z-notebook-2) laptop, but ethernet networking does't work (wireless doesn't work either, but I'd be happy with ethernet for now).

eth0 isn't listed in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

lshw does show the nic, but I can't make much sense out of the information:

```
$ sudo lshw -class network -sanitize
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wmaster0
       version: 01
       serial: [REMOVED]
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list logical ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k latency=0 module=ath9k multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Attansic Technology Corp.
       vendor: Attansic Technology Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: c0
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: pan0
       serial: [REMOVED]
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A link=yes multicast=yes
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, Ubuntu 9.04 does not currently support the Atheros AR8121/AR8113/AR8114/AR8131/AR8132 PCI-E Ethernet NICs.

To add support, I compiled and installed a kernel module:

1. Download AR81Family-linux-v1.0.0.10.tar.gz from http://partner.atheros.com/Drivers.aspx
2. tar -xzvf AR813X-linux-v1.0.0.9.tar.gz
3. cd src
4. make
5. sudo make install
6. sudo insmod atl1e.ko
7. service networking restart (wasn't necessary in my case)

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be easier to get your wireless working first then see if you can update over that, these instructions

```
 Re: Atheros ar928x wlan HELP
Code:

sudo su 
enter your password
echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/asus-laptop/bluetooth
echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/asus-laptop/wlan

__________________
AKA space_cadet in #ubuntu and ##windows
Ubuntu user #23413
```

from here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=930667 may help